# I am trying get back to previous activity but i get my menu activity

Tags: java, android, xml

this is my main activity---(1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okkLk.png)

here activity I want to go back to---(2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79wCe.png)

here from where i want back---(3)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlGX.png)

why when I use in previous btn I get my main activity and also when I make a btn to get previous  I get my main activity

```
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            updateUI();

        }
    });


}
private void updateUI() {

    Intent regTrip = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), regTrip.class);
    startActivity(regTrip);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Do go through this - https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new Intent, but instead of using Application Context, try using the name of the current activity you are in. For example, if the name of the current Activity was 'NewActivity', you would say:
 `startActivity(new Intent(NewActivity.this, regTrip.class));`

This would take you from the 'NewActivity' page to the 'regTrip' page.

Also you can just try adding onBackPressed() inside of your onClickListener. This is the built in method by android which is run when the user presses the back button on their phone. This means that when the user presses your back button, they are essentially doing the same thing as pressing the back button on their phone.

Answer (score 0):

Toast and Intent, both requires reference to context. And getApplication, getApplicationContext, LoginActivity.this and getBaseContext, they all offer reference to the context.

Now the thing confuses is the declaration of different contexts and their specific-usage. To make things simple, you should count two types of context available in the Android framework.

Application Context
Activity Context
Application context is attached to the application's life-cycle and will always be same throughout the life of application. So if you are using Toast, you can use application context or even activity context (both) because a toast can be raised from anywhere with in your application and is not attached to a window.

Activity context is attached to the Activity's life-cycle and can be destroyed if the activity's onDestroy() is raised. If you want to launch a new activity, you must need to use activity's context in its Intent so that the new launching activity is connected to the current activity (in terms of activity stack). However, you may use application's context too to launch a new activity but then you need to set flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in intent to treat it as a new task.

Now referring to your cases:

LoginActivity.this though its referring to your own class which extends Activity class but the base class (Activity) also extends Context class, so it can be used to offer activity context.

getApplication() though its referring to Application object but the Application class extends Context class, so it can be used to offer application context.

getApplicationContext() offers application context.

getBaseContext() offers activity context.

Go for activity context when using Intent and for toast you can use any context.